# Hive Metastore Configurations PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive

When I start Hive metastore service, my command line says: "Starting Hive Metastore Server" and nothing further. It doesn't actually start server, neither does it throws any error messages

Hive : 1.2.1
Hadoop : 2.7.1
Postgres: 9.3.8

hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/metastore</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>hiveuser</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>*****</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>org.jpox.autoCreateSchema</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

[metastore is actual database created in PostgresSQL, and I can access it using: psql -U hiveuser -d metastore]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the following property. especially for **PostgreSQL** . For more details  refer [here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.3/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap6-3.html)

```
<property>     
 <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>     
 <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property is replaced since Hive 2.0 by property **datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll** and others as explained in this [apache cwiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=82903061#ConfigurationProperties-datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll).

Please check other specific configurations in the same page.